# Visual Studio 2012 killed my WCF service reference

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have no idea what on earth happened.  I upgraded a project that I had in visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2012 and now the service reference is not recognized in either of them!

Comment: Re-add it then? Not entirely sure there is a question here....

Comment: I have tried to add re-add, delete and re-add.  Stop the service, delete, turn on the service re-add... Nothing seems to work... I am looking into some of the warnings and examples, and it would seem that it can not find schema Information for the element 'SavedWcfConfiguration'  Searching google as we speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that a particular library in my references (Newtonsoft.Json) was throwing an exception when I attempted to Reuse types in referenced assemblies.  I simply excluded that and the exceptinos went away.

Comment: Hi, Could you explain to me in detail how to solve this problem?